# Lebesgue outer measure in dilation invariant?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

For $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. We know that $m^*(A + t) = m^*(A)$. but Does it follow that

$$ m^*(\lambda A) = \lambda m^*(A)$$??? for $\lambda > 0$. Here $m*: P( \mathbb{R}) \to [0, \infty ] $ is lebesgue outer measure .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't follow directly. It follows from that $\{I_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ covers $A$ if and only if $\{\lambda I_j\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ covers $\lambda A$.

Comment: And the fact that for any interval $I$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, we have $l(\lambda I) = |\lambda| l(I)$. (As does the other property from $l(I+\lambda) = l(I)$.)